# How to "push" multiple values on one key in JavaScript Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Hi everyone i have the following problem. I have Map() that holds keys - System names, and values - nested Map() with key/value pairs component name/sub component name. I want to store multiple sub component names on one component name in the nested map. I try something like this when i get the same systemName and componentName in my code, but it didn't work.

```
mapName.get(systemName).get(componentName).set(subcomponentName, value);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: What's wrong guys? The question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Map` to provide automatic nesting:

```js
class NestedMap extends Map {
    get(key) {
        if(!this.has(key))
            this.set(key, new NestedMap);
        return super.get(key);
    }
}

//

let myMap = new NestedMap;

myMap.get('systemName').get('componentName').set('subcomponentName', 'xyz');

console.log(myMap.get('systemName').get('componentName').get('subcomponentName'))
```

Comment: sweet idea.....

Comment: Using `this.get(key)` will result in a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error or an infinite loop and `super.get(key)` will not. But I am confused: Why can the `super.method()` used to access the parent class method get the `key` in the current class?

Comment: @ooo: this is how inheritance works.

Comment: @ooo: yes, it is. `super` calls the method defined in the base class in the context (aka `this`) of the derived object.

Comment: I did a test and found: `super.method(arg) === super.method.call(this, arg)`. Is this awareness the key to answering the confusion I mentioned above?

Comment: @ooo: yes, you understood it quite right. The very idea of inheritance is that we take a function defined somewhere else (in a parent class or in a grand-grand-parent class) and run it as if it were defined in our own class, thanks to `this` magic.